# Why are some values negative when I call unproject () while using viewports

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a game I coded in java with libgdz for android and I figured out how to support multiple screen sizes with android but when I call camera.unproject (), the x value is negative and the y value is positive, but higher than the screen's bounds. But everything appears perfectly in place. Why does this happen?

Comment: Why does what happen? It looks like you'd expect your world units to be positive only, why would you expect that?

Comment: Use `viewport.unproject` when using viewports.

Answer (score 0):

Like grandmaster Xoppa already commented you should not expect your world coordinates to be positive. By default a camera's center sits at 0,0 of your world so if you unproject your top left screen coordinate we can expect it to return a negative X and positive Y. My guess is the default position of a viewport is the same. When you move the viewport or camera to the left it would increment your negative X value even more.

If you have a static viewport and want to have only positive world coordinates you should set it's position once it's created to the center of your world. This way the bottom left would be `0,0` and the top right would be `worldWidth, worldHeight`.

```
Viewport vp = new FitViewport();
vp.setScreenBounds(worldWidth / 2, worldHeight / 2, worldWidth, worldHeight);
vp.apply();
```

But now you probably only see the bottom left quarter of your game world. Since that is still sitting in the same world position. Also, you probably won't need this since the coordinates you get from unprojecting are "correct" and the objects you want to interact with are sitting in this "correct" coordinate system.